# How to check with jquery if @ is present in a string?

Tags: jquery

Why is this not working?

```
jQuery("#modalbuttonstep2").click(function() {
    if ( jQuery("#signupinput2").val().length > 3  && 
         jQuery("#signupinput2").indexOf('@') != -1 ) {
             jQuery(".modalstep2").hide();
             jQuery(".modalstep3").show();
    }
```

Comment: You are checking the `length` of one thing and using `indexOf` on another. What could go wrong?

Comment: You need to check a *string* value for `@`. If you look closely, you will notice you are not doing that. `;)`

Comment: thanks for your comments. i just got into jQuery today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the length of the value of the input but checking for the index of the `@` in the element itself. You need to be consistent. The best idea, since you're using the value multiple times, is to only get the value a single time and then use that return value in the rest of your function:

```
var value = jQuery('#signupinput2').val();
if(value.length > 3 && value.indexOf('@') != -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: works like magic! is != -1 the logical syntax or am i making two negatives one positive?

Comment: @user3397210 - It'll work. Personally, I prefer `value.indexOf('@') >= 0`. Makes things a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : jQuery("#signupinput2").val().split('@').length > 1 for checking @ existence.